# Help identifying obscure sci-fi movie from late 1970s/early 1980s

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I need help jogging my memory about a low budget science fiction film (or perhaps TV series) from the late 1970s or early 1980s.

The first scene of the movie depicts the characters on a disabled luxury cruise ship stranded in space. That's all I remember. I don't think it's Battlestar Galactica or Buck Rogers.

Comment: Arguably this question is better than the other, or at least its answer is. Perhaps a merge would be better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Lifepod*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125366/) from 1981.

> *"The first interplanetary cruise ship malfunctions halfway to Jupiter,
>   forcing most of the crew and passengers to abandon ship. A handful of
>   people are trapped onboard"*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifepod_%281981_film%29) has an abridged overview of the film's first act;

> The film takes place in 2191. The latest space liner for the Whitestar
>   Lines is the Arcturus, currently on its maiden voyage. On its approach
>   to Callisto, for unknown reasons, the ship's computer, the Main
>   Cerebral, declares a red five emergency, and orders "abandon ship".
>   Most of the crew and passengers leave in lifepods. Captain Montaine
>   (Christopher Cary) stays on the bridge. Cerebral begins to evacuate
>   the ship's compartments of oxygen. Third astrogator G.W. Simmons is
>   caught on deck 16 while it still retains an atmosphere. He runs into
>   Fiona Harrison (Kristine DeBell) a passenger from deck 15 who did not
>   leave with the others because she had to go back for her bird, Dwayne.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that has to be it! Wow, did you recall this from memory? My Google-fu didn't work trying to find the movie. Too bad there's only one brief snippet of the film on Youtube, with Russian overdubbing.

Comment: @RobertF - I've actually seen this. It was a remake of the (vastly superior) 1944 "Lifeboat" and was then remade in 1991 with the same title. Might I humbly suggest you watch the 1944 version instead.

Comment: I love that movie!  I was like a really long ep of The Outerlimits.